# Converting Foreach loop into linq form

Tags: c#, linq

I have `Dictionary<string,List<Member> members` and I have foreach loops. How to covert loop in loop into linq expression?

```
members.Foreach(x => x.Where(a=>a.Firstaname ?
```

```
foreach (var key in games.Keys)
{
  foreach (var val in games[key])
  {
    if (firstName == val.FirstName && lastName == val.LastName && command == val.CommandName)
    {
      val.Position = position;
    }
  }
}
```

need to set player's position if it matches data in dictionary

Comment: Have you tried it yet? Why do you want it in Linq anyway?

Comment: Post code that actually compiles. `Dictionary` doesn't have `ForEach`. You should really try to simplify the code though. If you iterate over a dictionary you get a `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` so there's no need to write something like `games[key]`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos that was my editing mistake, the dictionary line seems to be OP's start to convert the foreach loops.

Comment: @RenéVogt I was referring to `members`. The OP mentions dictionaries and yet `members` clearly isn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var items = games.SelectMany(x => x.Value).Where(val => firstName == val.FirstName && lastName == val.LastName && command == val.CommandName);
foreach(var i in items)
{
    i.Position = position;
}
```

Comment: Why go through the items twice, why not just update the property you need?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ This only iterates the items once.  Linq statements are evaluated lazily.

Comment: @juharr the answer is selecting many from the dictionary, so there's one access and then they are looping the new collection (items) again to set a property... There's no need to go over the new `items` just to set a property... Please explain how this isn't accessing this data twice...

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ `SelectMany` just flattens the internal lists that are the values of the dictionary.  And it's still going to be evaluated lazily.  So it will result in iterating over all the items in each of the lists in the values of the dictionary once.

Comment: @juharr you're missing the point, what I mean is `items` is the outcome that has already accessed the data it needs, but then a `foreach` is done on `items` just to update a property. You don't need to do this, it can be done without projecting the objects into a new var... This approach is backtracking... So you are still saying that the code above is only going over the items once to accomplish updating the property it needs?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ You don't seem to understand that `items` is an `IEnumerable<Member>` that's just an object that knows how to iterate the values.  It's not an actual collection that was created by iterating them already.  Now, if you put a `ToList` at the end then it would be iterating twice.

Comment: Understand, but why flatten and then loop this data, would you concur that just accessing the data you need and updating in one go is sufficient? The OP is just wanting to set a property, not have a reference to these items...

Comment: I mean using nested `foreach` loops to do that is fine if you're arguing against using Linq.  If you think there's some way to update the values via Linq then that's causing side effects which is bad practice with Linq.